# if -string- in set doesn't work

Tags: python, python-2.7, search

i'm trying to check if the input is in a set. I get the set from a `words.dat` file. the set is correct, but the `else` statement always gets executed. This is my code:

```
import fileinput
def words2array(words):
    woorden = set([])
    for line in fileinput.input(words):
        woorden.add(line)
    return woorden
def krijgInput():
    input = raw_input().upper()
    input += "/n"
    return input
woordSet = words2array("words.dat")
input = krijgInput()
if 'input' in woordSet:
    print "Ja"
else:
    print "Nee"
print input
print woordSet
```

This is a part of the set, I can't post the full set because it has around 80k-120k words.
`'SPOUT\n', 'BLASTOMA\n', 'HINDGUT\n', 'FORGOER\n', 'LEOPARDS\n', 'SPECULUM\n', 'KEROSENES\n', 'CARIED\n', 'SOUBISES\n', 'ANIMALS\n', 'DISSERTS\n', 'OMISSIVE\n', 'VIREMIC\n', 'FLUSTERING\n', 'PLENUMS\n', 'VACUITY\n',`

this is a little bit from `words.dat`:

```
AARDVARK
AARDVARKS
AARDWOLF
AARDWOLVES
AAS
AASVOGEL
AASVOGELS
ABA
ABACA
ABACAS
ABACI
ABACK
ABACUS
ABACUSES
ABAFT
```

Comment: All your words in the set have a newline character appended at the end, strip them first using `strip()`.

Comment: Voting to close as trivial typo. `if 'input' in woordSet:` searches for the string `'input'`. You don't want that.

Comment: I rolled back an edit that had removed one of the errors in the code. No idea how it got approved in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

You are checking for the literal string `'input'`, not the variable `input`, which you managed to use properly several times.

Also, don't use `input` as a variable name, as it masks the built-in.

And compare `/n` to `'BLASTOMA\n'` - `/` is different from `\`. Use `\n`.

And here's an easier way to do this:

```
with open('words.dat') as f:
    if raw_input().upper()+'\n' in set(f):
        print 'Ja'
    else:
        print 'Nee'
```

Note that that depends on having an "empty" line at the end of the file. If the last line is just the last word without a newline, use `if raw_input().upper() in set(map(str.strip, f))` instead.

Comment: Masking `input` in Python 2.x is not such a bad idea. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to strip the "`\n`"s: from the lines that you retrieve from the file:

```
for line in fileinput.input(words):
    woorden.add(line.strip('\n')) # strip
```

& change

```
if 'input' in woordSet: # check if string in set, wrong
```

to

```
if input in woordSet: # check if input in set
```

& as **@grc** mentioned in his comment below, in order for this to work, you need to drop this line

```
input += "/n"
```

so as to get the neat set of elements that you want.

Comment: @grc that too, thank you for the note.

Comment: He's adding a newline in the `raw_input` wrapper, so that shouldn't matter.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 he has the wrong slash, so it does matter

Comment: Ah, so he does... might want to mention that in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to search "input" as string in word set.

Please change below lines as:

```
input = krijgInput()
if input in woordSet:
```

Here you will search user input from set.